# 2D B-Spline approximation in Matlab

Tags: matlab, bspline

I am dealing with interpolation problems currently. I read about B-Spline approximation. So I tried to implement a matlab script for a better understanding of the B-Spline's mathematics.

In the first case I used my script to approximate a trapezoid B-Splines, which worked very well using four control points and the degree m = 3.
[image]

After that I added two more control points to check if the script runs correctly. But the approximation looks weird.[image]

I am using the mahematics from:
http://www.tm-mathe.de/Themen/html/funbezierbspline.html

So I think there is a mistake in my script. But I could not figure out where it is.

**Main script:**

```
%% Console
close all;
clear all;
format long;
clc;

%% Parameters

% Contron points
C = [0.0 1.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 7.0;  % x components
     0.0 1.0 1.0 0.5 0.5 0.0]; % y components

 C = [0.0 1.0 4.0 5.0 ;  % x components
      0.0 1.0 1.0 0.0]; % y components

% B-Spline Degree
m = 3;

% B-Spline
s = f_Bspline(C, m, 0.001);

%% Plot

figure(1);
plot(C(1,:), C(2,:),'o');
hold on;
plot(C(1,:), C(2,:),'--');
hold on;
plot(s(1,:), s(2,:));
grid on;
grid minor;
xlabel('x');
ylabel('y');
legend({'Control points','Polygon','B-Spline-Approx.'}, 'Location', 'southeast');
ylim([min(C(2,:)) max(C(2,:))*1.25]);
```

**f_BSpline:**

```
function s = f_Bspline(C, m, step)
% Calculates a B-Spline of degree m using the control points C.
% 
% C: 2-dimensional control points (x_0, ... , x_n; y_0, ... , y_n)
% m: B-Spline degree
% step: Step size of t.
%
% s: B-Spline. s(1,:) -> x component, s(2,:) -> y component

%% Parameters

% Control point's x and y components
x = C(1,:);
y = C(2,:);

% Number of control point - 1
n = size(x,2) - 1;

% Knot vector
T = f_BSpline_KnotVector(m,n);

% B-Spline intervall
t = 0:step:(n-m+1);

%% Calculate B-Spline

for z=1:1:size(t,2)
    ti = t(z);
    s(1,z) = 0;
    s(2,z) = 0;
    for i=0:1:n
        % Base B-Spline
        B = f_BSpline_BaseSpline(i, m, ti, T);
        % x component
        s(1,z) = s(1,z) + x(i+1) * B;
        % y component
        s(2,z) = s(2,z) + y(i+1) * B;
    end
end

end
```

**f_BSpline_KnotVector:**

```
function T = f_BSpline_KnotVector(m,n)
% Calculate knot sequence.
% m: Degree of B-Spline
% n: Number of control points - 1
%
% T = [t0, ... , t_n+m+1] : Knot sequence / vector

T = zeros(1, (n+m+2));
for j=0:1:(n+m+1)
    if j <= m
        Ti = 0;
    elseif j >= (m+1) && j <= n
        Ti = j - m;
    elseif j > n
        Ti = n - m + 1;
    end
    T(j+1) = Ti;
end

end
```

**f_Bspline_BaseSpline:**

```
function B = f_BSpline_BaseSpline(i, k, t, T)
% Calculate Base B-Spline B_i,k
% k: B-Spline degree
% T: Knot sequence
% t: Current t parameter
%
% B: Base B-Spline at t.

% Index shift
j = i + 1;

if k == 0
    % End of recusrion
    if t >= T(j) && t <= T(j+1)
        B = 1;
    else
        B = 0;
    end
else
    % Check dividing by zero
    if T(j+k) ~= T(j)
        A = (t -T(j))/(T(j+k) - T(j));
    else
        A = 0;
    end
    if T(j+k+1) ~= T(j+1)
        B = (T(j+k+1) - t) / (T(j+k+1) - T(j+1));
    else
        B = 0;
    end
    % Calculate base B-Spline
    B1 = f_BSpline_BaseSpline(i,   k-1, t, T);
    B2 = f_BSpline_BaseSpline(i+1, k-1, t, T);
    B = A * B1 + B * B2;
end


end
```

Comment: Some quick points: 1) In your main script, right after you define `C`, you redefine it in the next line overwriting the previous values. Is that intentional? 2) You don't approximate anything that way. You just define a B-spline through its control points and plot it. As a general rule, for a specific shape, if you use more control points to describe it the closer the control points will be to the actual geometry. But I don't see any approximation here: I would expect a given geometry and approximation through modification of the control points' coordinates (1/2)

Comment: 3) If you wanna play around, there is the [nurbs package](https://octave.sourceforge.io/nurbs/index.html) with a lot of functionality. NURBS are generalization of B-Splines. You can get B-Splines using weight w=1 for all control points or by using directly the correct functions. (If you use the nurbs package you will notice different implementation of the basis function computation. That's because the Cox de Boor formula is recursive and slow and more efficient algorithms can be derived. See such algorithms in "the NURBS Book" or in "A practical guide to splines") (2/2)

Comment: 1) Yes, I defined the control points twice to show you which I used to generate the plots above. But as I said, I used the mathematics of the postet link. I do not expect these "spikes" in figure 2, so I think there is a mistake in my script(s). 3) I will have a look at octave and the NURBS package.

Comment: Given the control points, the curve seems fine in both cases, optically at least. Regarding the NURBS package it's compatible with matlab too so choose what you like best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your evaluation of degree 0 basis functions at the internal knots. As there are no internal knots in your first example, the problem only becomes visible in the second example.

In **f_BSpline_BaseSpline** you write

```
    % End of recusrion
    if t >= T(j) && t <= T(j+1)
        B = 1;
    else
        B = 0;
    end
```

However, the website you linked suggests comparing with `<` instead of `<=`:

```
    % End of recursion
    if t >= T(j) && t < T(j+1)
        B = 1;
    else
        B = 0;
    end
```

This fixes the spikes
[image: improved version]
The problem was that at the interior knots your basis functions summed to more than one; note how the spikes point away from the origin.

However, if you look closer at the horizontal axis, you can notice another problem: the curve is now closed! The last degree 0 basis function *does* have to have a closed support, i.e., in that particular case there should be the `<=` that we have removed from your code. It is certainly a pity that the website did not explain that. So this is what the final result looks like:

[image: final result]

And here is the source code of the corrected **f_BSpline_BaseSpline**

```
function B = f_BSpline_BaseSpline(i, k, t, T)
% Calculate Base B-Spline B_i,k
% k: B-Spline degree
% T: Knot sequence
% t: Current t parameter
%
% B: Base B-Spline at t.

% Index shift
j = i + 1;

if k == 0
    % Corrected end of recursion
    if (t >= T(j) && t < T(j+1))
        B = 1;
    % Exception: the last basis function is equal to 1 also at the last knot.
    % There might be a more elegant way of writing it; I am no Matlab expert.
    elseif ( T(j+1) == T(end) && t == T(end))
        B = 1;
    else
        B = 0;
    endif
else
    % Check dividing by zero
    if T(j+k) ~= T(j)
        A = (t -T(j))/(T(j+k) - T(j));
    else
        A = 0;
    end
    if T(j+k+1) ~= T(j+1)
        B = (T(j+k+1) - t) / (T(j+k+1) - T(j+1));
    else
        B = 0;
    end
    % Calculate base B-Spline
    B1 = f_BSpline_BaseSpline(i,   k-1, t, T);
    B2 = f_BSpline_BaseSpline(i+1, k-1, t, T);
    B = A * B1 + B * B2;
end


end
```